# can't delete URL rewrites in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I have **43,806** rows under `Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management` but my `sitemap.xml` file contains only **2,035** URLs. I need to delete the entries in the `core_url_rewrite table` in order to get rid of duplicate meta tag issues that show up in Google Web Master. The problem is that the core_url_rewrite is empty and there are no records in it.

Where are all these URL rewrites stored? How do I get rid of these old URL rewrites?

I refreshed the "Catalog URL Rewrites" index as well but it didn't help.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

In Magento there is no table that stores the URL's that are shown in the sitemap.xml page. Those are automatically generated from your product collection at the time of request only. There is no relation to the core_url_rewrite table.